Finding the difference in rows of a table, and returning only the columns where values are different
I'm working on analyzing some data. I have a way of doing this in excel, but it's slow and too much manual work. I'd like to find a more effective way to find what I'm looking for.
Here's the scenario:
I have a DB table (multiple, but let's just focus on a single one for now) that has many rows and many columns. Think of this as transactional data and we can call it Table0. It looks like the sample below.
Table0 has differences in columns 0,2,3,5 and has identical data in columns 1,4. I need to process this table, and only return the columns with differences: columns 0,2,3,5.
I'm looking for a solution that will work with either Python or SQL (postgres) that can provide the sample output table below. It doesn't seem like a complex issue, but I don't have the luxury of time to get a custom solution running properly.
Are there any well-known methods of manipulating my data like this?
Table0
        C0   C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
    R0  aaa  ax   ay   aq   123  555
    R1  aab  ax   ay   aq   123  555
    R2  aac  ax   ay   aw   123  557
    R3  aad  ax   ax   aw   123  555
    R4  aae  ax   ay   aw   123  559
    R5  aaf  ax   ay   ae   123  555


Output
        C0   C2   C3   C5
    R0  aaa  ay   aq   555
    R1  aab  ay   aq   555
    R2  aac  ay   aw   557
    R3  aad  ax   aw   555
    R4  aae  ay   aw   559
    R5  aaf  ay   ae   555


A query returns a fixed set of columns, independent of table data. I.e. you need a two phase solution here. First find the wanted columns, then create a query selecting only those columns.

How many columns do you have?

@jarlh, Thats a reasonable idea, any suggestions on how to do it?

@Isolated, the tables I'm working with are 1k+ columns each. I did not design this and it cannot be changed.

Thanks to @ouroboros1 for the solution, full code to follow!
def main():

    csvFileList=os.listdir("data")

    dataFileList={}

    for csvFile in csvFileList:

        with open(f"data\\{csvFile}", mode='r', newline='\n') as curFile:
            curFileData = csv.reader(curFile)
            currFileList=[]
            for row in curFileData:
                currFileList.append(row)
            dataFileList[csvFile]= currFileList
    pandaList=[]

    for file in dataFileList:
        pandaList.append((file, pd.DataFrame(dataFileList[file][1:], columns=dataFileList[file][0])))

    for df in pandaList:

        filename = df[0]
        dataFrame=df[1]
        result = dataFrame.loc[:, dataFrame.nunique().ne(1)]

        result.to_csv(filename, index=False)


Using pandas:

Check where df.nunique is not equal to 1 using Series.ne and select with df.loc:

df.loc[:, df.nunique().ne(1)]

     C0  C2  C3   C5
R0  aaa  ay  aq  555
R1  aab  ay  aq  555
R2  aac  ay  aw  557
R3  aad  ax  aw  555
R4  aae  ay  aw  559
R5  aaf  ay  ae  555

The intermediate:
df.nunique()

C0    6
C1    1 # -> `False` with .ne(1)
C2    2
C3    3
C4    1 # -> `False` with .ne(1)
C5    3
dtype: int64


This worked exceptionally well! Thank you ourobos1!

After inspecting table contents, you want to run this query:
SELECT c0, c2, c3, c5 FROM table0;

Run this query to generate the query to run: :)
SELECT format('SELECT %s FROM table0;'
            , concat_ws(', '
               , CASE WHEN bool_or(t.c0 <> s.c0) THEN 'c0' END
               , CASE WHEN bool_or(t.c1 <> s.c1) THEN 'c1' END
               , CASE WHEN bool_or(t.c2 <> s.c2) THEN 'c2' END
               , CASE WHEN bool_or(t.c3 <> s.c3) THEN 'c3' END
               , CASE WHEN bool_or(t.c4 <> s.c4) THEN 'c4' END
               , CASE WHEN bool_or(t.c5 <> s.c5) THEN 'c5' END
               ))
FROM  (SELECT * FROM table0 LIMIT  1) s
CROSS  JOIN  table0 t;

The approach is to take a random row and check, for every column of interest,  whether any row has a different value. Exclude if so.
There are many ways, this should be among the fastest.
Run this query to generate the query to generate the query to run: :D
SELECT format($q$SELECT format('SELECT %%s FROM %1$s;'
            , concat_ws(', '
                       %2$s                
               ))
FROM  (SELECT * FROM %1$s LIMIT  1) s
CROSS  JOIN  %1$s t;$q$
            , attrelid::regclass
            , string_agg(format(', CASE WHEN bool_or(t.%1$I <> s.%1$I) THEN %1$L END', attname), E'\n                       ')
             )
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'public.table0'::regclass  -- your table name here!
AND    attnum > 0
AND    NOT attisdropped
AND    attname <> ALL ('{id}')               -- any columns to exclude?
GROUP  BY attrelid;

fiddle
Just provide the (optionally schema-qualified) table name where indicated, and an array of column names to exclude.
Table and column names are double quotes automatically where needed. See:

PL/pgSQL Looping through multiple schema, tables and rows
Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter

Assuming all relevant columns are defined NOT NULL, or we need to define how to deal with null values and implement that.
